# /bin/bash No such file or directory Connection closed

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I try to connect to a server using ssh (authentification is fine).

I got this:

```
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Connection to xxx closed.
```

Before, everything is working fine, Until I have really done something stupid and crushed the system, now I can't even connect.

I just installed the ubuntu 16.04 on that server. 
And I saw something I want is installed in /usr/local/lib64, but it used to be in /usr/lib64 in the previous version (12.04), so I did

```
mv /usr/local/lib64 /usr/
```

After this, nothing works. I can't even `ls` , the only command works is `cd`. When I exit and try to reconnect, I got this error. Now since that I can't connect, I can't even re-install.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Does `ssh SERVER /bin/dash -i` work? If not, what is the error message?

Comment: Wiping out the system library directory is problematic, in particular due to the common use of things like `libc.so`. Unless you've a means to run statically-compile binaries to repair the damage, a reinstall or rescue boot would be in order.

Comment: Can you still log into your account or not? Your question is contradictory: you say that you can't log in, and then you say that `cd` works. What works, what doesn't work? And **copy-paste** the exact commands that you typed and the resulting output, don't just say “it doesn't work”. If not, you'll need to log into that machine in a different way. We can't help you with that since we don't know how you've set it up. You may need to access it physically or to use a remote console.

Comment: `cd` works before I quit my session. But then I can't connect anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Ubuntu 16.04 installed anywhere yet, but based on current trends in Linux system layouts, I can make a pretty good guess at what happened here.

The old distinction between `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, and the distinction between `/lib` and `/usr/lib` has gone away, because it is no longer the case that we have to install systems on disks so small that we might not be able to get the full user environment onto it. That is to say, even a throwaway USB key is large enough these days for the full OS install, so we no longer need to make a distinction between single user mode tools that traditionally lived outside `/usr` and everything else, which was segregated under `/usr` somewhere.

Because a lot of software still believes in this distinction — for example, no current Unix or Linux type system has a `/local` or `/share` tree parallel to `/usr/local` or `/usr/share`, so you can't just get rid of `/usr` entirely — the common way for modern OSes to blur this old distinction away is to install everything in `/usr` and then symlink directories like `/usr/bin` out to `/bin`. (Or vice versa; it doesn't matter.)

Therefore, what you did with your `mv` command is blow away `/usr`, which was probably a symlink to the consolidated OS installation directory on your system. Not only does this replace `/usr/bin` and such, it also effectively replaces `/bin`.

In other words, because there was no `/usr/local/lib64/bin/bash` before you went in with your heavy-handed "fix", there is now no longer a `/usr/bin/bash` or a `/bin/bash`.

Solution: Boot your box into [rescue mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RescueMode) and restore the `/usr` tree to its prior state. You might need an existing working Ubuntu 16.04 system as reference to see how it should be restored.

As for your original problem, your `mv` command never was a good solution. If you want programs living in `/usr/local/lib64` to be runnable without an explicit path, add them to your shell's [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). On Ubuntu, this probably means editing `~/.bash_profile`.

Since you talk about a `lib` directory, you probably aren't dealing with executables, but libraries, in which case you probably need to add an entry to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` so that directory is added to the global library cache. See `man ldconfig` for details.